# Convert .SOBJECT file to .obj

Tags: windows, file

i don't know how to convert a .SOBJECT file (3D object file) from a game named Twelve Sky 2 into a .obj file to edit it and convert it back to .SOBJECT.

I would want to know if anyone know a tool or a way to convert it and convert it back so i can edit the file.